# how to change batch argument dynamically in jinja template depending on device size

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2

I have the below bootstrap panels, three col-xs-4 per row rendered in a jinja template, and it looks super nice on a desktop.

but when trying smaller devices it get ugly. so I want to know if there is a way to change the batch argument to 1 per row under a certain device size ?

or maybe there is a better approach, I'm very open as I'm very new to this :)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    {% for raceorganizers in res.keys() | batch(3, '&nbsp;') %}
        <div class="row">
            {% for raceorganizer in raceorganizers %}
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title"><a
                                    href="{{ raceorganizer.link }}">{{ raceorganizer.name }}</a><span
                                    class="text-right pull-right flag-icon flag-icon-{{ raceorganizer.country_code }}"></span>
                            </h3>


                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body panel-image">
                            <img class="panel-image-preview"
                                 src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/full/' + im ) }}" alt='{{ im }}'>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            {% for race in res[raceorganizer] %}
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></span>
                                        <span class="badge">{{ '{:.1f}'.format(race.distance_number) }}</span>
                                        <span class="flaticon-mountain40"></span>
                                        <span class="badge">{{ '{:.0f}'.format(race.elevation_number) if race.elevation_number is not none else '-' }}</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look more closely at bootstrap's [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/), you could completely get rid of the `batch` call. If you play with different tiers of classes (`col-xs` for phones+, `col-md` for desktops+) on the same element, you will be able to get bootstrap to split the content into 3 columns on desktops and 1 on smaller screens.